# MongoJS synchronous call

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm fixing some bugs in one project. I need synchronous cursor, to load data in loop.
I have code:

```
var mongo     = require('mongojs'),
    dataMaps  = [];

mongo.penguin_friends.find({ user_id_1: id_user }, function(err, friends) {     
    friends.forEach(function(data) {
        var cursor = mongo.penguin_user_maps3.find({ user_id: data.id_user }, { fields: { maps: 1 } });
    //I need to do dataMaps.push(cursor.data);

    });

    console.log("processingThisSomething()");

    processSomething();     
});
```

I need to complete this request before calling processSomething(); So I need to process mongodb query inside a loop synchronously.

Comment: It's not possible to make the queries synchronous. The API doesn't support it. But, you can use an iterator that supports asynchronous blocks. E.g., [`async.each()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each).

Comment: Could you please give an example in aswer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to make the queries synchronous as the API doesn't support it.

You'll have to provide a callback to [`.find()`](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs#dbcollectionfindcriteria-projection-callback) or [a `cursor` method](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs#cursor) to receive the results:

```
cursor.toArray(function (err, maps) {
    if (!err) {
        dataMaps.push(maps);
    }
});
```

But, you can replace the iterator with one that's asynchronous-aware, such as [`async.each()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), to continue when they've completed:

```
async.each(
    friends,

    function (data, callback) {
        var cursor = mongo....;

        cursor.toArray(function (err, maps) {
            if (!err) {
                dataMaps.push(maps);
            }

            callback(err);
        });
    },

    function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            processSomething();
        }
    }
);
```